# High cpu usage mostly by System process. stdriverx64.sys. Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, cpu

System process uses 20-45% of cpu when idle. Process Explorer shows that it's connected with stdriverx64.sys. I found information that it may be connected with audio drivers. I tried to uninstall them from Device Manager, but after restart they were back and nothing has changed. What can I do now?

I wanted to provide some images but I need at least 10 rep to do so. That's sad.

- Windows 7 Home Premium 64
- Toshiba Satellite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are partially correct kfinto.

stdriversx64.sys is connected to audio software. This is a driver that is most often utilized by NCH known as Sound Tap.

Uninstalling the software by NCH will resolve this issue.

Comment: This software wasn't present on the machine, but I installed it and then uninstalled and this resolved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

On my laptop running Windows 7 Professional this stdriverx64.sys was also eating up 25% and more (a full core power). It seems it was triggered on by some video(s?) in browser tabs (occured with Chrome and Opera).

Uninstalling NCH Tone generator didn't change significantly. Then uninstalling SoundTap seemingly solved the problem. I stll have their WavePad installed. We'll see